# $\operatorname{ker}f=\operatorname{ker}f^2 \quad \Leftrightarrow\quad\operatorname{im}f=\operatorname{im}f^2$

Tags: group-theory

Let $f:G\rightarrow G$ be an endomorphism of finite groups and $f^2:=f\circ f.$ Then

> $\operatorname{ker}f=\operatorname{ker}f^2 \quad \Leftrightarrow\quad\operatorname{im}f=\operatorname{im}f^2$

Is this true?

What if they are of infinite order?

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840858/operatornamekerf-operatornamekerf2-quad-leftrightarrow-quad-operatorna/4840859#4840859

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general.  Consider the group $G = \mathbb{Z}^\infty$, and the map $f:G\to G$ defined by $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) \to (x_2, x_3, x_4, \dots)$. This and its square are both surjective, but $(1, 1,0,0,0\dots)$ is in ${\rm Ker}(f^2)$ but not ${\rm Ker}(f)$.